# Download file, spring boot e angular 2

Tags: spring-boot, angular2-services

Would you help me?

Hi, I'm having the same problem.

```
    public FileSystemResource patch(@RequestBody List<Especie> especies, HttpServletResponse response) {
     filename=\"somefile.pdf\"");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+"nomeArquivo"+".xls");
```

//      return new FileSystemResource(new File("xxx"));

```
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(especies);
    List<String>  nameColumns = especies.get(0).getColumns();

    List<IExcel> list = castList(especies);
```

//      List resource = this.service.exportFileExcel(list, nameColumns, response);

```
    File retorno = this.service.exportFileExcel(list, nameColumns, response);
    return new FileSystemResource(retorno);
```

//      response.setContentLength(bytes.length); // opcional
//      response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);

Comment: "The same problem"? Please explain exactly what the problem is, because right now it is totally unclear what your question is about.

Comment: I have a controller (back end) that returns a fileSystemStream and I do not know how to get it on the front end (angular 2)

Comment: Send a list to a back end with the contents of the file


And I give a subscribe to get the return and it comes null.


this.especiesActionsService.patchExportFileExcel(this.exportEspecies);
        this.file$.subscribe( item=> {
            console.log("item",item);

            if ( item ) {
                this.downloadFile(item);
            }
        })

Comment: Hello, I solved it in a different way, using ng2-excel-export, follow link below
I get simpler

Https://github.com/luwojtaszek/ng2-excel-export